# Gulp watch работает, но не обновляется less

Tags: javascript, gulp

Работает корректно, но почему то нет автообновления стилей

```
gulp.task('less', function(){ // Создаем таск "sass"
return gulp.src('src/less/style.less') // Берем источник
    .pipe(less()) // Преобразуем less в CSS посредством gulp-sass
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/css')) // Выгружаем результата в папку app/css
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true})) // Обновляем CSS на странице при изменении
});

gulp.task('watch',['browser-sync', 'less'], function() {
gulp.watch('src/less/*.less', ['less']); // Наблюдение за less файлами
 gulp.watch('src/*.html', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch('src/js/**/*.js', browserSync.reload);

});
```

Comment: Эм... Гальп ждёт выполнение задачи `browser-sync`, которая, видимо, запускает сервер, который **не завершается**, а **ждёт** запросы. Соответственно, задача не завершается и задача `watch` не работает.

Comment: Какое решение можете предложить?

Comment: нет автообновления html и стилей

Comment: Ну у меня примерно так: `gulp.task('serve', _ => {browserSync.init({...});gulp.watch(...);});`. Работает и сервер, и наблюдатели.